# Multiple Screen

Tags: android, layout

i create a project that will support any 5" to 7" screen with any density, from mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi. So i add folder layout-large, layout-sw600dp instead of layout folder.

But when i tried to compile this project on Samsung Galaxy S4 and myPad Tablet, the place and the size of the button is not as same as on the layout that i've created.

I have used this code in my manifest.

```
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <!-- all xlarge size screens -->
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" 
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"/>
```

But the button and textview don't fit to the screen. Any suggestion?

Comment: Post your layout file which you have added in layout folders

Comment: Make folder named: "layout-480x320" put the layout files for the above devices in there. Precisely for the S4 this should work.

Comment: in the folder, which device should i choose for the xml? @AstralProjection

Comment: Choose 3.2 from the Graphical Layout in XML.

Comment: it still not works.. :|

Answer (score 0):

You need draw different layout in different size device Create layout folder in res

1. layout-xlarge
2. layout-large
3. layout-normal
4. layout-small

and create same xml in different size layout folder so that you can custom layout in different size device

Comment: i have created the layout-large and layout-xlarge..
In the layout-large i used 5.1" WVGA, in layout folder i used Nexus 4 (4.7"), in layout-sw600dp i used 7" WSVGA, but it didn't work.. x_x

Comment: Remove layout-sw600dp and create that four folder, it will detect your device size and choose the correct size. So you just create your custom layout in different size.... For example : nexus 7 will choose layout-large, nexus 10 will choose layout-xlarge ..

Comment: i create these folders, but i can use only the layout-large for nexus 7.. in the layout-normal i can only use nexus 4, if i want to use 5.1" WVGA, it automatically changes the xml in layout-large, from nexus 7 to 5.1" WVGA.. :|

Comment: what is the diiferent for folder "layout" and "layout-normal"? @henry4343

Comment: layout is a default folder.. If your device don't have correct layout, it will choose file.xml in layout folder

Comment: if i used the layout-normal and layout-large, so what is the default for "layout" folder?
i already set only the layout-large for nexus 7, but the display on my tablet is not exactly the same with the display i made on the xml file.. why?

Comment: I already told you... It will detect you device and choose correct layout folder.. so you don't worry about device which you have, just design your custom layout in different size.

Comment: For example, if you have layout, layout-normal, layout-large, and you install your app in nexus 10, it will choose layout folder because you don't have layout-xlarge folder

Comment: when i set the device on xml in layout-large to nexus 7, why it is automatically changed the device on xml in layout folder into nexus one?

Comment: i have used the layout-normal, large, and xlarge, but no one fits on my tablet. When i add layout-sw600dp, it fits on my 7" tablet, but the three other layout folders still not fit on my Samsung Galaxy S4 although i have set for 5.1" device..